# how to pass a command line argument to a c++ file through a python code?

Tags: c++, python

i am compiling a c++ file in python code using this os.system("rc.cpp") and then os.system("./a.out") . I would like to pass a command line argument to the rc file . how do i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "running a c++ file". You can compile c++ code and link it into an executable that you then run. Are you trying to compile it? What c++ toolchain are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to call other executables. [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) takes a list as it's first argument. The first item in the list is the executable you'd like to call. All list items are the arguments passed to the executable.

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['/usr/bin/foo', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
```

Comment: so suppose there is something called foo.py and foo.cpp . which one should it take ? and how does it compile foo.cpp if you give /usr/bin/foo?

Comment: It doesn't compile anything, it just lets you call an external executable. If you want to compile it, you'll have to call a compiler of some sort. The example I gave would call /usr/bin/foo. If you wanted it to call /usr/bin/foo.py, you'd need to put that in there.

Comment: according to the question that i have asked about how to run a C++ code . Using Popen how am i supposed to do it?

Comment: You compile it with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at scons:  http://www.scons.org/

The build configuration files you write for it are python scripts.